# Relativistic mass and relativistic charge

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, charge, mass, inertial-frames

Let a particle with a mass $m$ and a charge $q$ move with a speed $v$ close to the speed of light ($v\approx c$). Then, the special theory of relativity tells us the particle's relativistic mass would increase in a factor $\gamma = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(v/c)^2}}$. Nonetheless, the particle's charge would not be modified (at least that is what my Optics textbook, Óptica Electromagnética, Cabrera) states. This has me thinking, if an observer is located in an inertial frame of reference from where he can measure the speed of the particle, then said observer will also perceive the particle's mass is greater. Why won't he perceive any alterations in the particle's charge?

Comment: Why would they perceive changes in the charge? This is well tested with relativistic electron beams.

Comment: The concept of "relativistic mass" is nowadays deprecated. Instead, we prefer to talk about rest mass, which is a Lorentz invariant quantity

Comment: Please, do not discuss relativistic mass. It is not a useful quantity. Causes more confusion than it is worth.

Comment: Charge density is a component of the 4-vector current density $J^\mu$ and is subject to the Lorentz transformation; charge, however, is a scalar quantity and is Lorentz invariant. Thanks to Thomas Fritsch for clarification.

Comment: unfortunately for us all teachers and popular science books persist in teaching "relativistic maths". This question is just one of many illustrations of why this is a bad approach

Comment: I like relativistic mass, and Feynman talks about it, which is good enough for me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The way we deal with electric charge in relativity is to introduce it as part of a complete set of ideas about electromagnetic fields and charged bodies. You are quite right that in this formulation the amount of electric charge on a given body is independent of the inertial frame in which the body may be being observed. We say it is 'invariant' or (to be clear) 'Lorentz invariant'. The word 'invariant' means the same, at any given event, no matter what inertial reference frame may be being adopted to define spatial and temporal coordinates.

Another important Lorentz invariant property of any particle is the rest mass $m$. In terms of this quantity, the momentum of a body moving at speed $v$ is
$$
p = \gamma m v.   \tag{1}
$$
Our thinking is clearer if we regard $m$ as the important mass-related property here, not $(\gamma m)$. The equation setting out how the momentum relates to a vector force is
$$
{\bf f} = \frac{d {\rm p}}{dt}   \tag{2} 
$$
Hence
$$
{\bf f}
= \frac{d\gamma}{dt}m {\bf v} + \gamma \frac{dm}{dt}{\bf v} + \gamma m \frac{d{\bf v}}{dt}.
$$
For forces from electromagnetic fields the rest mass doesn't change as the particle accelerates, so this simplifies to
$$
{\bf f} = \frac{d\gamma}{dt}m {\bf v} + \gamma m \frac{d{\bf v}}{dt}.
$$
Notice that this is *not* $(\gamma m)$ times the acceleration.
I have mentioned this to give you some idea of why it is that it doesn't help much to gather the Lorentz factor and the rest mass together and call the combination by a name such as 'relativistic mass'. It's better to think of the situation as a given rest mass and then a momentum related to that by the formula (1). The important point is that the rest mass is the same in all inertial frames. That means that in order to find the momentum in any given frame you have to use the combination $\gamma v$ (which can depend on the frame) and multiply by the same $m$ no matter which frame it is.

Once you have settled that idea, you will also see that the ratio of charge to rest mass, for any given body, is the same in all inertial frames. When a body of given charge and rest mass is accelerated by an electric field, the charge and rest mass stay fixed while the momentum increases. The degree to which the momentum is sensitive to force is also fixed (see equation (2)). But as $\gamma$ gets larger the acceleration $d{\bf v}/dt$ gets smaller, for any given force.

Comment: "amount of electric charge on a given body is independent of the inertial frame." This does not answer the question, "Why...?"   The proof of that is derived in textbooks.

Comment: @JerroldFranklin I have written such a book. The invariance of charge is not derived but proposed as an axiom. But the axioms can be motivated by considerations of elegance and simplicity.

Comment: If it is derived, why does it have to be an axiom?

Comment: It is not derived! Whatever derivation you saw had to be based on some set of ideas which took, e.g. Maxwell's equations as their starting point. But to obtain those equations the most natural argument is to start from some sort of invariant scalar (or introduce a 4-vector flux) to act as source, so the invariance comes first and the equations are among those that can describe fields consistent with that. You can, alternatively, assert the equations axiomatically and then derive invariance of charge but then how did you arrive at those equations?

Answer (score 0):

This is a derivation to answer the question:

> Why won't he perceive any alterations in the particle's charge?

The continuity equation is equivalent to the conservation of electric charge.

We apply Gauss's law in four dimensional space-time to show that the vanishing of the four-divergence of $j^\mu$ leads to the total charge being Lorentz invariant. That is, the total charge given by $\int\rho\, d^3 r$ is the same in all Lorentz systems.

[image]

The quadrilateral ABCD
represents a four dimensional hypervolume in system S. Think of the $y$ and $z$ axes as both coming out of the paper in four dimensions.

In a Lorentz transformation, the $x,t$ axes transform
to the $x',t'$ axes. Note that for a Lorentz transformation
the x and t axes rotate by the same angle, but in opposite directions.
We apply Gauss's law to the hypervolume inside the quadrilateral, resulting in integrals over the hypersurfaces represented by the sides of ABCD.  The integral over sides AD and BC are integrals in $dtdydz$ with $x$ fixed.  (There are additional integrals, with $y$ fixed and $z$ fixed, that are not pictured.)

If the sides AD and BC are removed to spatial infinity, and the current density vanishes at infinity, the integrals over those sides (and the integrals with $y$ and $z$ fixed) will vanish.  Then the full surface integral will be given by the two integrals over sides AB and CD.

The side AB represents a three-dimensional spatial volume at constant $t'$, while the side CD represents a spatial volume at constant $t$.
The integral over side AB is the volume integral $\int\rho\, d^3 r$,
which equals the total charge at fixed time $t$
in system S. Similarly, the integral over CD equals the total charge at a fixed time $t'$ in system S'.  Due to the vanishing of the four-divergence of $j^\mu$, the integral over all surfaces of the hypervolume is zero, which means that the integrals over sides AB and CD are equal.  Thus, we have shown that the total charge must be the same in each Lorentz system. This is true even though the integral $\int\rho\, d^3 r$ does not look like a Lorentz scalar.

Note that the Gauss's law integration must be done in a single system, and
in this case, we chose system S. The surface represented by side AB has two interpretations.  It is one surface of the hypervolume in system S (with $t$ varying along the surface), but is also a surface at fixed $t'$ in system S'.

If the hypersurface AB had been chosen to be at fixed $t$, instead of fixed $t'$,
we would have proven that the total charge is a constant in time in a single system.

Answer (score -1):

> Why won't he perceive any alterations in the particle's charge?

This is assumed because electric charge is operationally defined (practically determined) by the electric field it creates, e.g. via the surface integral

$$
\epsilon_0 \int_\Sigma \mathbf E \cdot d\mathbf \Sigma = Q.
$$
Electric field transforms between inertial frames in such a way (Lorentz transformation of the Faraday tensor) that this integral has the same value in all frames. This is assuming no charge transport through the boundary is happening, because if net charge inside $\Sigma$ changes with time, it is a function of time, and thus (since simultaneity is frame-dependent) it depends on the frame of reference.

Comment: The proof is more complicated because (as you say) the bounding surface changes in a Lorentz transformation. It's too complicated to put here, so I recommend going to a textbook.

Comment: @JerroldFranklin you're right, but that is not what I'm saying.

Comment: I did misread your answer.  You have to apply a four-dimensional Gauss;s law to the four-divergence of $j^\mu$ to show that the total charge given by $\int\rho\, d^3 r$ is the same in all Lorentz systems.